# Binary digits compression

Tags: algorithm, compression, winrar, winzip

I need to build a large program as a project for school and I've been thinking about a file compression like winzip/winrar.
I read about types of algorithms and their examples but the problem is that all the examples are presenting the implementation on alphabetic strings
and it's not helping me because file is not a string, it consists of a succession of zeros and ones.
For example, if I have a file - " 0111000110111001 "
how can I compress it?

Comment: What do you mean with succession of 0 or 1? Do you mean a sequence of "0" and "1" characters? Of bytes with the value 0 or 1, or a series of bits? What is the data structure that is being represented by those values?

Answer (score 0):

Even if the examples that you've seen use alphabetic strings, at machine level, it's still a succession of 0 and 1. If you want to apply those examples to your binary file, you can read it byte by byte, or word by word. By this way, what you've seen for alphabetic strings will still be available.

Comment: I feel like I missed something, the way I see it: File - eventually is a succession of 0 and 1 that stored in somewhat memory. The more the file has bits the larger it gets in its size.
All the examples of compressing are talking about alphabetic/numeric strings and showing how to compress them into a shorter alphabetic/numeric code, but when I tried it on binary succession it only makes it longer which mean the size will be larger accordingly.
I want to take the file's bits and make its length of succession shorter than it really is so the size will gets smaller accordingly.

Comment: How do you read the file ? Byte by byte ? Or ? What kind of compression do you use ? In most cases, methods that compress strings aren't suitable for compressing binary files.

Comment: The only way I know right know is reading a binary file Byte after Byte.
But still even when I read a single Byte in the file, how can I compress it?
For now I use C languege to read a binary file but the thing is that the parameters of "fread" and "fwrite" accept minimum size as byte so I was thinking maybe I'll read a Word (16bit) and try to compress it to a Byte but I don't know how to implement the algorithm on the binary system.

Comment: What algorithm do you use ?

Comment: For a start I've been thinking about the LZW I have a well understanding of how to implement it on strings. I thought maybe create a dictionary that will locate successions of Words and give each of them a Byte successions code that will replace the Word in the new compressed file but the problem is the maximum of successions I can store in that dictionary is as the theoretical amount of Byte 256 and the amount of Word successions is 65,536 which means I can cover only 1/256 successions from the maximum theoretical amount and I'm not sure it's enough unless I missed something in the algorithm.

Comment: I don't know about this algorithm. I've looked at it a bit on the internet, you must choose the size of a character, read the file character per character and update the dictionnary. If you have a well understanding of the algorithm, you can easily implement it just by reading your file character per character.

Comment: I realized that LZW doesn't fit so I moved on to Huffman algorithm and now I'm trying to implement it.
I hope to succeed and if I have more quastions I'll ask here. Thanks anyway.